# How do I create a new version of my Connected App?

Tags: oauth

I just joined a company that is working on a Connected App in Salesforce. The previous programmer set up the Connected App. He is no longer with our company. I am changing the app. I need to change the Callback URL. If I look here:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=connected_app_create.htm#oauth

I see:

```
These are version-independent fields that bypass the packaging or   installation lifecycle. Users of the connected app will see things like the   description change. The following fields have this version-independent   behavior.
```

The fields are:

```
Description
Info URL
Logo Image URL
Callback URL
```

So to change the Callback URL I need to create a new version. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create new version or create new connected app.

- Go to that **Connected App**
- Click "**Edit**"
- Change the *Callback URL*
- Click **Save**

You would see something like this:
[image]

Version is still **1.0**

But this change will be reflected in all package installations or app which are using this connected app. Make sure that it won't break existing apps. Your app will redirect to new Callback url.